# How to prefill a field of a node using rules in Drupal7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-rules

Using rules it's easy to fill field values of a node after user pressed the save button. Just add a rule on before saving content event. But is it possible to have a rule to prefill a node field before edit form is shown to the user? So he has a change to corrent the default values.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/rules_forms

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late reply, but hopefully someone might find it to be of some help:

If you are creating the node using Rules, you could save it first, selecting "*Force saving immediately: true*". In the next step, you could set the value of the node field. You might need to save again. (also 'Force save' immediately.) And in the next step, do a 'page redirect' to the edit url.

Not sure if this is an elegant way to do it, but it might work. I had a somewhat similar requirement (not the same), and this is how I finally did that - by saving first, and then redirecting to the edit url of the saved node.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something you can accomplish with rules or not, but if you go to structure->content types you can click "manage fields" and edit the default value of any field other than the title field (which you could always turn off and replace with a custom title field with a default value)

Comment: Well, I asked about rules precisely because I need to set the default value based on other entities. Static constant is not enough for my case.

Comment: As far as I can tell it can't be done using rules, but could easily be done in a module using hook_form_alter

Answer (score 0):

I think there are basically two ways of doing this:

1) Use Rules Forms. I don't know very much about that module, and I have had some less than perfect experiences with the module, but I'm fairly certain it could be done with the module.

2) Use Rules to create a node, populate the relevant field values, and *then* send the user to the edit page. One downside with this approach is that if the user decides to abort the node creation, you'll end up with a half-populated node that needs deletion in one way or another.

If you choose to go for option 2, and are comfortable with Page manager and Panels, it is probably worth checking out the Rules Panes module.